# Python 3 Tkinter Issue: Gui doesn't show unless another gui is activated

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I don't get it. I know I'm making a mistake somewhere, I just can't find it and it irritates me. A lot.

For the basic tester thing, Tkinter isn't supposed to be this damn tough. But try as I might, I can't view the GUI, even though if I run another piece of code, something I copied letter by letter from a course, it works perfectly, and not only that the GUI I tried to implement pops up like nothing's wrong.

```
Python 3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

background = ttk.Frame(root)
background.pack()

leftpane = ttk.Frame(background)
leftpane.pack(side = LEFT)

text = ttk.Label(leftpane, text = "I AM A STRING.")
text.pack()

rightpane = ttk.Frame(background)
rightpane.pack(side = RIGHT)

moretext =ttk.Label(rightpane, text = "THIS IS A STRING AS WELL.")
moretext.pack()

button1 =ttk.Button(leftpane, text = "I AM BUTTON.")
button1.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop
```

This is the code that doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()


one = ttk.Label(root, text = "one")
one.pack()

two = ttk.Label(root, text = "two")
two.pack()

three = ttk.Label(root, text = "three")
three.pack(side = LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

this is the code that does.

Comment: First thing I noticed is `mainloop` without `()` in your first snippet. Just a typo i assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the last line of the first code is:

```py
root.mainloop
```

it is supposed to be:

```py
root.mainloop()
```

you forgot the parentheses

Comment: don't forget to mark my answer as the answer to close the question